# have I found a bug in BASH?

Tags: bash, bugs

EDIT: the bug disappears by version 4.3.8.

I am using `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. I believe I have found a bug. Would like to know if perhaps I'm missing something or if my bug is version/platform specific.

Bash's history functions will utilize the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable, if defined. So if

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%s
```

Then, `history` produces:

```
60  1460542926 history
```

Additionally, `history -w` results in the history file containing:

```
#1460543065
cat $HISTFILE
#1460543082
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%s
#1460543084
history -w
```

**However**, if the variable is defined in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28085062/3849157):

```
: ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:=%s }
```

then the output from `history` is correct, but `history -w` **fails to write the timestamp headers** to `$HISTFILE`.

```
unset HISTTIMEFORMAT
: ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:=%s }
history -w
```

If I then simply do `export HISTTIMEFORMAT` or `declare HISTTIMEFORMAT`, the problem goes away. However, if the variable is *instead* auto-exported via `set -a`, it doesn't work.

I could not reproduce this kind of result with a different variable, `PS2`.

---

### From version 4.3.8 running on an Mint 17 / Ubuntu system

#### Method 1

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ bash --norc
bash-4.3$ HISTFILE=/tmp/histfile.$$
bash-4.3$ history -c
bash-4.3$ HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
bash-4.3$ history
    1  1460642608 HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
    2  1460642610 history
bash-4.3$ history -w
bash-4.3$ cat $HISTFILE
#1460642608
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
#1460642610
history
#1460642612
history -w
bash-4.3$
```

#### Method 2

```
$ bash --norc
bash-4.3$ HISTFILE=/tmp/histfile.$$
bash-4.3$ history -c
bash-4.3$ : ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:="%s "}
bash-4.3$ history
    1  1460642758 : ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:="%s "}
    2  1460642763 history
bash-4.3$ history -w
bash-4.3$ cat $HISTFILE
#1460642758
: ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:="%s "}
#1460642763
history
#1460642769
history -w
bash-4.3$
```

---

### From RHEL6 and RHEL7 systems

including `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and `version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

#### Method 1

```
~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
~$ bash --norc
bash-4.1$ HISTFILE=/tmp/histfile.$$
bash-4.1$ history -c
bash-4.1$ HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
bash-4.1$ history -w
bash-4.1$ cat $HISTFILE
#1460643571
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
#1460643573
history -w
bash-4.1$ exit
```

#### Method 2

```
~$ bash --norc
bash-4.1$ HISTFILE=/tmp/histfile.$$
bash-4.1$ history -c
bash-4.1$ : ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:="%s "}
bash-4.1$ history -w 
bash-4.1$ cat $HISTFILE
: ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:="%s "}
history -w 
bash-4.1$ history
3  1460643602 : ${HISTTIMEFORMAT:="%s "}
4  1460643606 history -w 
5  1460643608 cat $HISTFILE
6  1460643719 history
```

Comment: If you think you have found a bug, you could report it directly to the Bash project.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yep, but first doing "field validation" and seeing if maybe this was fixed and/or introduced at a certain point.

Comment: Seen also in version `3.2.25`

Comment: Check the most recent version, not an older version. Debian experimental has `4.4~rc1-1`. That would be a reasonable version to test. You didn't mention your distribution. Apparently some Red Hat one, so probably one of CentOS/RHEL or Fedora. In any case, try the most recent of bash you can to test it. Alternatively, you could build from the most recent available sources.

Comment: @FaheemMitha the version information indicates redhat :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (according to the poster) the Bash bug described has been fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: I think it should be closed, but not removed due to the obvious utility of it being something someone else might encounter in the near future. I just don't see a proper classification for being closed.

Comment: If you want, write an answer saying it is a fixed bug, and then accept it. That works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research indicates it was a bug and fixed sometime between the 4.2.x and 4.3.6 releases.